# How does the code use the regex to match the info in the URL here?

Tags: django

```
class FourDigitYearConverter:
    regex = '[0-9]{4}'

    def to_python(self, value):
        return int(value)

    def to_url(self, value):
        return '%04d' % value
```

```
from django.urls import path, register_converter

from . import converters, views

register_converter(converters.FourDigitYearConverter, 'yyyy')

urlpatterns = [
    path('articles/2003/', views.special_case_2003),
    path('articles/<yyyy:year>/', views.year_archive),
    ...
]
```

How does the regex variable is used to match the year info in the URL? It is just a class variable.

It is from Django docs so I think it must work somehow. Anybody knows how this snippet works? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Django would take list of path converters and convert each match found in paths path string to regex parameter using [`_route_to_regex()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/urls/resolvers.py#L204) at initialization

URLresolver would then when called match your URL using regex formed by all converted parts and map return value to proper type by calling converters to_python function

to_url is used for reverse()